# Can I use environment variables inside a character range in grep?

Tags: unix, terminal, sh

I have a list.txt of things, say :

```
Apples
Bananas
Ananas
Coconut
Kiwi
Nuts
```

and 2 environment variables STARTCHAR and ENDCHAR. I want to grep fruits that starts with a character inside the range [$STARTCHAR-$ENDCHAR].

This works :

```
grep '^[A-C]' list.txt | sort
```

so i get :

```
Ananas
Apples
Bananas
Coconut
```

but I want the letter range to be the two variables STARTCHAR and ENDCHAR. I tried

```
grep '^[$FT_LINE1-$FT_LINE2]' list.txt | sort
```

but I get this error

```
grep: invalid character range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep "^[$FT_LINE1-$FT_LINE2]"
```

Single-quoted strings are not evaluated for substitutions. Double-quoted ones are.